# Cooja technical information needed

Tags: c, rtos, contiki

I am a newbie to [Contiki RTOS](http://www.contiki-os.org/index.html). I have installed Conitiki on Ubuntu and I have also installed [Cooja](http://www.contiki-os.org/start.html#start-cooja) network simulator. I tried running "Hello world" from the examples directory and I succeeded. But I want to understand the terms when the COOJA comes up. Terms like UDGM, No Radio Traffic, MRM categorized under Radio Medium are very new to me.

Please let me know about the basic tutorial where in the explanation is included with each of these "Radio Medium" options with source codes.

Though I have been browsing through the Contiki-2.5 directory for various examples, I am trying to make a sense out of it by reading all that and co-relating with the terms I encounter and often googling and using wiki too..

But I get lost and it looks huge..

Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about comprehension of documentation and a specific application domain technology.

Comment: "alk" thanks for the answer, yes indeed there is very little information on Cooja and Clifford says its off-topic and is about a specific application domain technology. Well @Clifford please let me know if Stackoverflow is only meant for questions to the more dominant and wide spread technologies. At some point of time Cooja would also be somewhat popular so is knowledge sharing very limited on Stackoverflow .. Moreover the keyword "Cooja" was available to tag for the question I asked ..if you are the admin would please consider adding Cooja as a tag keyword

Comment: You can add any words you like as tags.  The most commonly used ones come up as suggestions, but you can use others.  The scope of questions acceptable on StackOverflow is clearly stated at http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic - arguably it comes under "software tools commonly used by programmers", but that is normally interpreted as programming related tools, rather than application domain tools not directly related to programming.  If the question were about the RTOS that might be legitimate, but the simulator is better dealt with by a more specific community forum.

Comment: If the documentation is inadequate, that would be best addressed by the authors perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

As Cooja is mainly used in research, writing documentation is unfortunately not as appreciated as it should - unless it's in form of a paper published at a conference or in a jurnal. Basically there are the following sources of information. (Sorry I haven't got the reputation to post more than two Links)

- Publications: https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=cooja You might need to do a bit of searching.
- The Wiki: https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/wiki Information is still a bit sparse, but I'm sure you're welcome to help.
- The source code: github.com/contiki-os/contiki/tree/master/tools/cooja - This is the most reliable resource, but you might need some time.
- The Mailing List. You can search it using dir.gmane.org/gmane.os.contiki.devel or get more information about subscribing at the wiki.
- The Website: www.contiki-os.org - Although it improving quickly, it's not the right place for in-depth information.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to understand UDGM: UDGM: Distance Loss, UDGM: Constant Loss, and DGRM, but I seem to explain hard to you clearly by my poor English. 
But, I can try it.

UDGM: Distance Loss, Under the radio, The signal loss is related to distance, RSSI decline along with distance increasing. This way like the real.

UDGM: Constant Loss, Under the radio, The signal loss is related to a const number.
This way is a target condition, it is useful for research.